# Using Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.SpeechSynthesizer how to capture when is done speaking in C#

Tags: c#, azure-cognitive-services

I have code in c# Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.SpeechSynthesize to output some text to speech. synthesizer.SpeakTextAsync(text) This is done asyncronlesly. In another thread I would like to either check the state of synthesizer for example "isSpeaking" or have an event fire when SpeakTextAsync has completed. I see there is this SpeechSynthesizer.SynthesisCompleted but I can't figure out how to implement and have not found samples.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out

```
synthesizer.SynthesisCompleted += synth_SpeechOver;
```

Than handle the event

```
    public void synth_SpeechOver(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //code
    }
```